# div does not wrap text after AJAX call

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have an problem with an div. The div wraps the text fine if I do it the following way:

```
<div class="ChatBox">
        <div id = "AllMessages" class ="AllMessages" style="position:absolute;width:100%;">fljadhfldhsfkljasdhfkjddasfasdfasafsdhasflhdasfhasdfjhdhasfkladfsdsf</div>
</div>
```

However, when I perform an AJAX call and use javascript to change the content of the div (insert the content that is returned by the AJAX call) the wrapping doesn't work.
The result that is returned is an HTML-table if that has anything to say?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById('AllMessages').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
```

It just adds a scrollbar to the panel so it is possible to scroll to the right to see the whole content.

Hope anyone can help.
Thanks!

Comment: add the properties height:auto and overflow:auto to the class AllMessages. hope this will work..

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon 
Thanks for your reply!
Got it working by mixing your solution and just setting the HTML-table options in the file where the AJAX-function is.

Comment: added as answer so that it would be more helpful for others who experience this situation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify the css property to

```
.AllMessages
{ 
height:auto
overflow:auto
}
```

hope this will work.